# Why do I have far less partitions created with repartition("codeDept"): 67 than the number of distinct values I see doing a groupBy("codeDept"): 101?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why do I have such behavior?

Using Spark `3.4.2`, The partitioning of a dataset by department code leads to 67 partitions.
But then a `groupBy("codeDepartement").count()` on it, for checking,
to show the distinct values this `codeDepartement` can take,
displays 101 groups.

I was expecting the same number of partitions than distinct department codes.

```java
etablissements = etablissements.orderBy(col("codeDepartement"), col("siren"), col("siret"))
   .repartition(col("codeDepartement"));

LOGGER.info("Il y a {} établissements actifs aux communes valides dans {} partitions.",
   etablissements.count(), etablissements.rdd().getNumPartitions());

LOGGER.info("Codes départements distincts, dans ce dataset : ");
etablissements.groupBy("codeDepartement").count().show(1000);
```

```
Il y a 14709213 établissements actifs aux communes valides dans 67 partitions

Codes départements distincts, dans ce dataset : 
+---------------+-------+
|codeDepartement|  count|
+---------------+-------+
|             54| 118128|
|             11|  99033|
|             69| 462425|
|             29| 169582|
|             07|  70540|
|             51| 126975|
|             15|  35271|
|             42| 142343|
|             87|  69451|
|             73| 136969|
|             64| 176657|
|             30| 171753|
|             34| 333064|
|             59| 417050|
|            974| 158693|
|             01| 114847|
|             28|  74275|
|             22| 118072|
|             85| 132900|
|             52|  29831|
|             35| 213147|
|             16|  71013|
|            973|  43430|
|             47|  75910|
|             31| 313410|
|             18|  52267|
|             27|  98568|
|             61|  52689|
|             75|1167263|
|             17| 160377|
|             26| 122050|
|             46|  47033|
|             77| 247903|
|             05|  48813|
|             60| 126640|
|             68| 137721|
|             2A|  51698|
|             71| 103812|
|             43|  48347|
|             70|  41612|
|             09|  38379|
|             78| 278139|
|             89|  63519|
|             90|  22390|
|             19|  57178|
|             41|  60072|
|             23|  28192|
|             55|  30827|
|            976|  27994|
|             95| 231905|
|             93| 348487|
|             08|  44373|
|             38| 270196|
|             40| 107055|
|             25|  97574|
|             2B|  53280|
|            971| 118740|
|             02|  76853|
|             03|  63757|
|             44| 279770|
|             92| 394392|
|             86|  79835|
|             81|  83366|
|             33| 404454|
|             06| 379786|
|             67| 225994|
|             84| 144356|
|             79|  67285|
|             24|  99988|
|             32|  54861|
|             88|  69851|
|             56| 152193|
|             37| 115680|
|             49| 144513|
|             65|  57282|
|             39|  52247|
|             62| 197474|
|             83| 299061|
|             04|  48078|
|             13| 520638|
|             14| 143628|
|             21| 114411|
|             82|  56187|
|             53|  56914|
|             58|  38995|
|             48|  20713|
|             36|  41752|
|             10|  61800|
|             63| 130870|
|             12|  69965|
|             66| 123858|
|             91| 225435|
|             94| 286322|
|             72|  87984|
|             74| 205585|
|             76| 198632|
|            972| 114396|
|             80|  94665|
|             50|  89945|
|             57| 164594|
|             45| 110986|
+---------------+-------+
```

(101 `codeDepartement` values in this table)

The number of partitions created by `repartition(column)`
isn't the same number than distinct values that can be found within values of that `column`?

I was taking this for a fact, with Spark,
(provided there isn't thousands of distinct values willing to serve as a key value for partitioning (then a `repartitionByRange` is better)).
But it's not guaranteed?

---

If you want to reproduce that problem on your computer,

then download one `StockEtablissement.csv` file from
[INSEE Base Sirene](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-sirene-des-entreprises-et-de-leurs-etablissements-siren-siret/)

[image]
(click on the download arrow)

I took one of year 2023.

Then run this short program:

```java
Dataset<Row> etablissements = sparkSession.read().format("csv")
   .option("header", true)
   .option("quote", "\"")
   .option("escape", "\"")
   .load("/data/comptes-france/sirene/2023/StockEtablissement.csv");

etablissements = etablissements.select("siren" ,"etatAdministratifEtablissement", "siret", "codeCommuneEtablissement")
   .filter("codeCommuneEtablissement IS NOT null AND etatAdministratifEtablissement = 'A'")
   .withColumn("codeDepartement", col("codeCommuneEtablissement").substr(1, 2));

etablissements = etablissements.orderBy(col("codeDepartement"), col("siren"), col("siret"))
   .repartition(col("codeDepartement"));

LOGGER.info("Il y a {} établissements actifs dans {} partitions.",
   etablissements.count(), etablissements.rdd().getNumPartitions());

LOGGER.info("Codes départements distincts, dans ce dataset : ");
etablissements.groupBy("codeDepartement").count().show(1000);
```

In this case, it will display:

```
Il y a 14735282 établissements actifs dans 14 partitions.

Codes départements distincts, dans ce dataset :
+---------------+-------+
|codeDepartement|  count|
+---------------+-------+
|             07|  70540|
|             51| 126977|
|             54| 118129|
|             15|  35271|
|             11|  99033|
|             69| 462427|
|             29| 169582|
|             42| 142343|
|             87|  69451|
|             73| 136969|
|             64| 176659|
|             30| 171755|
|             34| 333068|
|             59| 417051|
|             01| 114848|
|             22| 118075|
|             28|  74275|
|             85| 132909|
|             35| 213147|
|             16|  71015|
|             52|  29831|
|             71| 103812|
|             98|   1423|
|             47|  75910|
|             43|  48347|
|             31| 313411|
|             18|  52267|
|             70|  41612|
|             61|  52692|
|             27|  98569|
|             75|1167271|
|             17| 160377|
|             26| 122051|
|             09|  38380|
|             46|  47033|
|             78| 278140|
|             77| 247904|
|             89|  63519|
|             05|  48813|
|             60| 126640|
|             90|  22390|
|             68| 137721|
|             19|  57179|
|             41|  60072|
|             23|  28192|
|             2A|  51698|
|             55|  30827|
|             93| 348488|
|             08|  44373|
|             95| 231906|
|             03|  63758|
|             38| 270197|
|             40| 107056|
|             25|  97575|
|             02|  76853|
|             2B|  53280|
|             44| 279772|
|             82|  56187|
|             53|  56920|
|             92| 394393|
|             86|  79835|
|             58|  38995|
|             81|  83366|
|             33| 404455|
|             06| 379790|
|             48|  20713|
|             97| 487810|
|             67| 225994|
|             84| 144359|
|             79|  67286|
|             24|  99989|
|             32|  54863|
|             88|  69851|
|             56| 152193|
|             36|  41752|
|             10|  61800|
|             37| 115680|
|             49| 144516|
|             63| 130870|
|             65|  57282|
|             39|  52247|
|             62| 197474|
|             12|  69965|
|             83| 299061|
|             04|  48079|
|             13| 520640|
|             14| 143630|
|             21| 114411|
|             66| 123858|
|             94| 286322|
|             91| 225435|
|             74| 205585|
|             72|  87984|
|             76| 198632|
|             80|  94665|
|             50|  89950|
|             45| 110986|
|             57| 164596|
+---------------+-------+
```

Number of partitions and distinct `codeDepartement` aren't the same.

---

If I do the experience VaibhavG suggests, of setting `spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled` to `false`
or `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` to `false`

(my configuration is then

```
hadoop.tmp.dir=/data/tmp
java.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.app.name=Config Entreprises (test)
spark.app.startTime=1707741438759
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g
spark.driver.memory=2g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.executor.memory=3g
spark.home=/opt/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3
spark.local.dir=/data/tmp
spark.logConf=true
spark.master=local[12]
spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=false
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=false
spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled=true
spark.sql.legacy.allowHashOnMapType=true
spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite=CORRECTED
```

)

the number isn't 14 anymore, but 200, which looks worse to me.

A sign that Spark doesn't take care of my partitions wish, and does how it wants.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey I can't find the .csv file you're referring to. In the link you sent it seems like there are a bunch of PDF files and some .zip files that contain a CSV but with the wrong column names. Could you specify exactly which file we can take and where we can find it?

Comment: @Koedlt Thanks for your help. I've downloaded the file StockEtablissement2024 from there, an `head -n2 StockEtablissement_utf8.csv` shows the good columns: |`siren,nic,siret,statutDiffusionEtablissement,dateCreationEtablissement`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of exactly which version you are on, so let's assume you're on version 3.5.0. To explain what you're encountering we need to delve into the source code.

In order to not make this too long, I'll just add links when we jump from function call to another. The relevant code I will paste into this answer.

When you do `df.repartition(col)`, you're doing the following:

- executing [`repartition(partitionExprs: Column*)`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3680-L3682)
- executing [`repartitionByExpression`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3639-L3653) with `numPartitions` = `None`
- this adds a [`RepartitionByExpression`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L1843-L1864) node to the logical plan (with `optNumPartitions` = `None`)
- its partitioning is defined by the [`HasPartitionExpressions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L1805-L1834) trait
- in this trait, you can see how the number of partitions is defined:

```scala
val numPartitions = optNumPartitions.getOrElse(conf.numShufflePartitions)
```

- so in our case, since `optNumPartitions` = `None`, we get the value of `conf.numShufflePartitions)`:

```scala
def numShufflePartitions: Int = {
  if (adaptiveExecutionEnabled && coalesceShufflePartitionsEnabled) {
    getConf(COALESCE_PARTITIONS_INITIAL_PARTITION_NUM).getOrElse(defaultNumShufflePartitions)
  } else {
    defaultNumShufflePartitions
  }
}
```

Now we have enough information to understand what you see:

- since you're not supplying any number of partitions to your `repartition` call, it will use one of both:

  - if AQE is enabled, AQE will determine the number of partitions
  - if AQE is disabled, you will get `defaultNumShufflePartitions`, which defaults to 200

#### Conclusion

`df.repartition(col)` does not repartition your dataframe into the same amount of partitions as the unique count in `col`. It repartitions your dataframe into partitions that follow your configuration (either it uses AQE or it uses `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`).

If you absolutely want to have the same amount of partitions as unique values, you will need to specify this in your `repartition` call by adding the number of partitions as an input parameter. I rewrote your code in Scala as an example and used the `Sirene : Fichier StockEtablissement du 01 Fevrier 2024` file:

```scala
val etablissements = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("header", true)
   .option("quote", "\"")
   .option("escape", "\"")
   .load("StockEtablissement_utf8.csv")
   .select("siren" ,"etatAdministratifEtablissement", "siret", "codeCommuneEtablissement")
   .filter("codeCommuneEtablissement IS NOT null AND etatAdministratifEtablissement = 'A'")
   .withColumn("codeDepartement", col("codeCommuneEtablissement").substr(1, 2))
   .orderBy(col("codeDepartement"), col("siren"), col("siret"))

val numPartitions = etablissements.select("codeDepartement").distinct.count
val output = etablissements.repartition(numPartitions.toInt, col("codeDepartement"))

println(s"Il y a ${output.count()} établissements actifs dans ${output.rdd.getNumPartitions} partitions.")

Il y a 15516749 établissements actifs dans 98 partitions.
```

**Final note**: Without any more context, this seems like adding computational complexity for no reason. If you wish to persist partitioning information to disk when writing away your dataframe, I would advise to use `df.write.partitionBy()`. You can read some more about `repartition` vs `partitionBy` in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700051/15405732).

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer! The reason I need to have one partition per department, is that they are many things (establishments, accounting, equipment...) that can be partitioned into departments. With the interest that most of the time, the user who studies one city and its surrounding (local authority, for example) is looking at cities within one (or two at most) departments. Loading `enterprises_of_dept43` with `accounting_of_dept43` with `equipment_of_dept43` if they need to be joined, can be interesting.

Comment: But I fear something, after what you're explained me: if I was doing the `distinct.count` and the `repartition(numPartitions.toInt, col("codeDepartement"))` it would ensure me that I have the same number of partitions than departments, could I be sure that partition 1 would contain only one specific `codeDepartement`, partition 2, another different `codeDepartement`?

Comment: To respond on your last question: yes, each partition will contain only values with the same codeDepartment. But in general, partitions help to parallelize your computational workload. If you want to put all the data relevant for one specific user inside of 1 partition in memory, this will rather work against you. As I said in the end of my answer, you'll probably want to write away a partitioned dataframe using `partitionBy`. This will speed up future queries made by users if they are only interested in 1 specific department.

Comment: thanks for your precision. It's not a partition for a user, it's for an area. It comes under sense when considering a territory. I think that if you are in the U.S., for example, you might find convenient to partition you data considering the state too: because when a user will query data of many kinds for joining and researches, most of the items he will link together will have a lot of chances to come from the same state. When you are in Alaska, you don't need to load data from the Colorado. You don't block access to them, but expect that Spark will mostly stay around Alaska parquet files

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell you what your are doing ,

`df.repartition(col('someColumn'))`

when you mention a column name to `repartition` function, what spark did is the following,

1. make a 64b hash of the column value
2. perform a modulo on that hash value
3. the result of that modulo operation determins the partition number.

Thats why , you think number of distinct `value == number` of partition .

But then in spark there are some things called configuration precedence,

example while determining partition size and number ,

spark first check whether AQE is enabled or not , if so then what VaibhavG told will happen .

then spark check if `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value ,

when you disabled AQE , it automatically switched to shuffle partition ,whose value is `200` , thats why you are getting `200` .

if you want to create partitions based on unique values of that column , use

`df.partitionBy(col('some_col'))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanations too! But `df.write().partitionBy(...)` can be only used when you're about to write your dataset somewhere, on a physical support. What tricked me, was that I didn't figure things could be different "in memory" and "when partitioning for writing".

Comment: If, one side, I do an `etablissements = etablissements.repartition(col("codeDepartement"))`, that leads to 14 partitions, in order to use that `etablissements` dataset in join for a complex operation, but that another side, I want to keep it and do a save with an ``etablissements = etablissements.write().partitionBy("codeDepartement")`, won't have Spark double job of reshuffling all?